# Как использовать стрововые ресурсы string-array из кода

Tags: java, android, массивы

Пытаюсь создать Expandable ListView в Fragment и с ходу вопрос, во всех гайдах массивы для названия групп и списков используются так:

```
 // названия компаний (групп)
    String[] groups = new String[] {"HTC", "@Samsung", "@LG"};

    // названия телефонов (элементов)
    String[] phonesHTC = new String[] {"Sensation", "Desire", "Wildfire", "Hero"};
    String[] phonesSams = new String[] {"Galaxy S II", "Galaxy Nexus", "Wave"};
    String[] phonesLG = new String[] {"Optimus", "Optimus Link", "Optimus Black", "Optimus One"};
```

Есть ли вариант вынести их в строковые ресурсы, чтобы дальше при переводе приложения на другие языки не столкнуться с данной проблемой? Пытался в строковых ресурсах создать

```
<string-array name="1-10">
        <item>Раз</item>
        <item>Два</item>
        <item>Три</item>
        <item>Четыре</item>
        <item>Пять</item>
        <item>Шесть</item>
        <item>Семь</item>
        <item>Восемь</item>
        <item>Девять</item>
        <item>Десять</item>
    </string-array>
```

но приложение вылетает, вываливается ошибка, о том что данный массив пуст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

видимо сначала нужно получить массив-объект из ресурсов и уже его передать в адаптер, а не ссылаться напрямую на ресурсы в адаптере:

```
 String[] group1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.group1);
```

аналогично для других строковых массивов в ресурсах.

PS: так же, имя массива в ресурсах (и вообще переменных в Java) должно начинаться с букв и содержать ограниченный набор символов (латинские буквы, цифры, знаки $ и _ ). Имя *1-10* не подходит

Comment: по поводу имени массивов в курсе, для примера сюда написал.